Python equivalent for openssl sha256 & base64 encoding
I have bash shell script with this command:
openssl dgst -binary -sha256 < $body | openssl enc -e -base64

body is a json object.
I need equivalent command in Python3, can you please help
This is what I tried, the encoded string is not matching with output from bash script
import hashlib, base64


hash_object = hashlib.sha256(body.encode('utf-8'))  
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()

BYTE_ARRAY = bytearray.fromhex(hex_dig)

print(f"{BYTE_ARRAY}")
BASE64_VAL = base64.b64encode(BYTE_ARRAY)
print(f"{BASE64_VAL}")`


For me, both codes return the same Base64 encoded hash for the same input data, s. online on jdoodle here and here, so not reproducible. The JSON serialization may be missing or the formatting or even the content may be different. Post sample data (JSON data, hashs of both codes).

Works for me given the input is correct, but you don't need to convert to hex and back:
echo test >inputfile; openssl dgst -sha256 -binary <inputfile | openssl base64
-->
8sobtsfpB9Btr+Roflefznazfk6Tt2BQItpS5szCb9I=

import hashlib,base64;
d=open('inputfile','rb').read();
h=hashlib.sha256(d).digest();
print(base64.b64encode(h).decode('ascii'))
-->
8sobtsfpB9Btr+Roflefznazfk6Tt2BQItpS5szCb9I=

